# Dynamic id name

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I got this template:

```
<ion-view view-title="MAP" name="tab-map">
    <ion-content has-tabs="true" style="text-align:center;">
        <div style="width:100%;height:400px;" ng-attr-id="{{'canvas_map_'+place.id}}"></div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

and I'm trying to set div's content dynamically by passing through controller:

```
angular.module('helloDynamicMap', ['ionic'])

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ionicConfigProvider) {

    $ionicConfigProvider.navBar.alignTitle('center');
    $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');
    $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.text('').icon('ion-chevron-left');
    $ionicConfigProvider.backButton.previousTitleText(false);

    $stateProvider

        .state('main', {
        url: "/main",
        controller: "PlacesCtrl",
        //abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/main.html',
        resolve: {
            resultPlaces: function (findPlace, $stateParams) {
                return findPlace.all();
            }
        }
    })

    .state('place', {
        url: "/place/:placeId",
        //abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/place-tabs.html',
        controller: 'PlaceCtrl',
        resolve: {
            resultPlace: function (findPlace, $stateParams) {
                return findPlace.get($stateParams.placeId);
            }
        }
    })

    .state('place.details', {
        url: '/details',
        views: {
            'tab-details': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/details.html'
            },
        }
    })

    .state('place.map', {
        url: '/map',
        views: {
            'tab-map': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/map.html' //,
                    //controller: "MapCtrl"
            }
        }
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/main");

})

.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $rootScope) {

    // button back
    $scope.goBack = function () {
        console.log("back button");
        $state.go("main");
    }

})

.controller('PlacesCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, resultPlaces) {

    // Get places
    $scope.places = resultPlaces;

    // Button back
    $scope.goTabs = function () {
        $state.go("tab.map");
    }

})
.controller('PlaceCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, resultPlace) {

    // Load place's data in scope's model
    $scope.place = resultPlace;

    var div = document.getElementById("canvas_map_" + resultPlace.id);
    console.log("div", div);    

    // Create Map
    var map;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        var div = document.getElementById("canvas_map_" + resultPlace.id);

        // Initialize the map view
        map = plugin.google.maps.Map.getMap(div);

        // Wait until the map is ready status.
        map.addEventListener(plugin.google.maps.event.MAP_READY, onMapReady);
    }, false);

    function onMapReady() {
        var button = document.getElementById("button_" + resultPlace.id);
        button.addEventListener("click", onBtnClicked, false);
    }

    function onBtnClicked() {
        map.showDialog();
    }

})

.factory('findPlace', function ($q) {

    // list all places

    var places = [];
    places = [{
        id: "1",
        name: "Place A",
        details: "details for Place A",
        latitude: "28.472143",
        longitude: "-81.469856"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        name: "Place B",
        details: "details for Place B",
        latitude: "",
        longitude: ""
    }, {
        id: "3",
        name: "Place C",
        details: "details for Place C",
        latitude: "",
        longitude: ""
    }];

    return {
        all: function () {
            var dfd = $q.defer();
            // resolve promise
            dfd.resolve(places);

            // return promise
            return dfd.promise;
        },

        get: function (placeId) {
            for (var i = 0; i < places.length; i++) {
                if (places[i].id == parseInt(placeId)) {
                    return places[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
})
```

This code works perfectly when I use static id name as "canvas_map_01", but doesn't works when I tries to set it through scope variables.

The main question is how to set and handle div elements through dynamic id name:

```
// Load place's data in scope's model
$scope.place = resultPlace;

var div = document.getElementById("canvas_map_" + resultPlace.id);
console.log("div", div);
```

My full code is on [Github](https://github.com/brunovinny/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-dynamic), please somebody can tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please show how `resultPlace` looks like?

Comment: I mean can you `console.log(resultPlace)` in `PlaceCtrl` controller and post the result?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide it returns: {id: "1", name: "Place A", details: "details for Place A", latitude: "28.472143", longitude: "-81.469856"}

Answer (score 1):

-Change your html from

ng-attr-id="{{'canvas_map_'+place.id}}"

To

id="{{'canvas_map_'+place.id}}"

-Change your code from 
var div = document.getElementById("canvas_map_" + resultPlace.id);

To

var div = angular.element("#canvas_map_" + resultPlace.id);

Than it will work fine